# Facing issue in installation of flutter in my laptop

Tags: flutter, dart, installation, src, failed-installation

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxpCI.png)
I am facing issue in installation of flutter in my laptop. I am unable to open the.bat file to move further in the installation process. also in cmd, whenever typing "FLUTTER" the window is getting closed on its own.
The error image is above.

i have tried opening the .bat file for further installation process "flutter doctor, etc." I have kept all the flutter files in a separate src folder in c drive. Installed GIT also.
Actually I am trying to install flutter by cloning but then i tried installing it by zip file. Still not getting the results.

Comment: What guide are you following to install flutter on your system?

Comment: Im doing it on my own and also following a course from udemy

Comment: I have a feeling your course is outdated or something, you are supposed to download the Flutter zip that you are supposed to unzip and then use

Comment: So I downloaded the zip and then just extracted it. Still not working

Comment: I installed Flutter using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqHOtlh3Dd4&ab_channel=WsCubeTech around a week or so ago everything worked fine, check it out